# POST is dumping in the inspector "response", but not displaying on the browser page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, debugging

I am on linux, using apache. The dump shows in the response category of the page inspector, but the browser is not showing the same data.

javascript post code

```
    const eHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()

    eHttp.open("POST", "post.php", true)

    eHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')

    eHttp.send(JSON.stringify(dataMap['user']))
```

php code:

```
echo $_POST;

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: And what does it show? And what do you expect? You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example. Furthermore `$_POST` is an array and can't be echoed.

Comment: I tried to post an image but I don't have enough reputation. I'll just copy the data.

Comment: Inspector: Arrayarray(2) { ["username"]=> string(6) "myuser" ["password"]=> string(6) "mypass" } myuser

Comment: Browser page: ArrayNULL

Comment: I expect the browser to show the same data which is showing in the inspector's response.

Comment: No images please... Why do you do this `json_decode` stuff? Comment this out.

Comment: The `response` in the developer console is where results of an AJAX event would log. What are you doing with the response after getting it?

Comment: Actually https://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make Mistake #7 explains why you must manually decode the json string that you post when using the content header application json.

Comment: @user3783243 I am not doing anything with the response. I was only looking there to see if the data is posting correctly and echoing correctly. It does, except when I visit the file post.php in the browser, I do not see the same data. It's very odd.

Comment: @7Z2S5 When you visit the page are you sending JSON payload as well? If not `php://input` is empty so you get empty result.

Comment: I am not sending anything when I visit the page.

Comment: `php://input` empty so `file_get_contents` is FALSE so `json_decode` returns `NULL`, `null is returned if the json cannot be decoded` That matches up with previous documented behavior, https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/973969774876962866/978382116024905768/unknown.png. Could do a `!empty` on `$_POST` or `file_get_contents('php://input')`, if empty maybe take in `$_GET` you could debug that by adding parameters to URL

Comment: I wish that were true but it does it even without that line.

Comment: `echo $_POST;` is an array so that too would fail.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not really reach a conclusion here. I kind of see where you're going with your suggestion about file_get_contents, but it's getting sticky at this point.

Comment: I was only echoing it to see it's data type.

Comment: You need to send header for data type to be correct. This is sounding like XY problem https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I apologize my good sir I am but a humble idiot. Thank you for your time and effort.